# what is the form variable

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

I have this template in twig :

```
{% form_theme form _self %}  

{% block body %}

<div class="container">
    <h1>creer une nouvelle annonce</h1>

    {{ form_start(form) }}

        {{ form_widget(form) }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">créer la nouvelle annonce</button>

    {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}

</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block form_row %}

<pre>
    {{ dump() }}
</pre>
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

and this is the output of the dump function in my chrome:

```
array:32 [▼
"value" => ""
  "attr" => array:1 [▶]
  "form" => Symfony\Component\Form\FormView {#707 ▶}
  "id" => "ad_title"
  "name" => "title"
  "full_name" => "ad[title]"
  "disabled" => false
  "label" => null
  "label_format" => null
  "multipart" => false
  "block_prefixes" => array:3 [▶]
  "unique_block_prefix" => "_ad_title"
  "row_attr" => []
  "translation_domain" => null
  "label_translation_parameters" => []
  "attr_translation_parameters" => []
  "cache_key" => "_ad_title_text"
  "errors" => Symfony\Component\Form\FormErrorIterator {#708 ▶}
  "valid" => true
  "data" => null
  "required" => true
  "size" => null
  "label_attr" => []
  "help" => null
  "help_attr" => []
  "help_html" => false
  "help_translation_parameters" => []
  "compound" => false
  "method" => "POST"
  "action" => ""
  "submitted" => false
  "app" => Symfony\Bridge\Twig\AppVariable {#277 ▶}
]
```

[schreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9drv3.png)

What is the `form` variable in line number 4 of output of dump function above

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Screenshots for code or text output are not useful. You cannot copy/paste them, they are not indexed when someone search on the site, you need to open two different pages to have the full info... Please edit your question and add your dump as a code block directly in your question. Thanks.

Comment: hi i jsut edited the question details

Comment: it's an object of class [FormView](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/symfony/symfony/source-class-Symfony.Component.Form.FormView.html#16-162)

Comment: i did not understund !
pelase can you explain more?

Comment: It hold the instance of the `FormView` you've registered/created in your [controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-forms-in-controllers)

Comment: and what is FormView  ?

Comment: is it true that it contain the data of current widget/label?

Comment: Yes, it contains all the information of the inputs u've added